# Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am working on project in Laravel 5.4 where I have used mail function 
that is

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyAccountByEmail($user));
```

but I am getting this error

> Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.

Earlier it was working properly but now it starts showing me that error.

Answer (score 1):

you must check your mail driver in config/mail.php file

Answer (score 1):

please check you .env configuration file especially

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```